# ESLint: Cannot start language service process / problem with HLS .ts extension

Tags: angular, webstorm, eslint, http-live-streaming, angular-eslint

IMPORTANT: Please see UPDATE EDIT below which provides vital info

I keep getting this error showing in WebStorm 2021.2.2 (and other recent version) when using Angular:

> ESLint: Cannot start language service process

See screenshot below

All .ts files report a similar error:

> ESLint: Can not get result from language service

I tried to reproduce the problem by creating a new Angular project as follows:

```
ng new video-and-event-listeners-test --style=scss --routing=true
cd video-and-event-listeners-test/
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics --skip-confirmation
```

Initially everything worked OK but then the error returned and I cannot get rid of it. I have this error in every project (my projects all contain HLS files - see edit below). The `ng lint` command just hangs. WebStorm just fails when you run a code inspection. Any ideas how to fix this please (without just disabling eslint)? Working without eslint is like digging a hole without a spade :(

Other versions of relevant software:

```
Node.js version 14.17.3
@angular/cli@12.2.6 (global install)
Angular 12.2.0
eslint 7.26.0 (installed by the above `ng add` command)
```

UPDATE EDIT:

OK I finally have a lead to go on! I have a directory as follows:

/src/assets/test-videos

This folder contains a bunch of HLS streaming videos. The HLS video chunks / segments have a .ts extension. A .ts extension is standard for HLS chunks but they seem to be causing ESLint to fail (since ESLint is linting .ts files). If I delete the entire folder, ESLint starts working!!! When I restore the folder, ESLint stops working.

So I tried to put the folder on ignore by adding a .eslintignore file in my project root with the contents:

```
src/assets/test-videos/**/*
/src/assets/test-videos/**/*
./src/assets/test-videos/**/*

src/assets/test-videos/*
/src/assets/test-videos/*
./src/assets/test-videos/*

src/assets/test-videos/
/src/assets/test-videos/
./src/assets/test-videos/

src/assets/test-videos
/src/assets/test-videos
./src/assets/test-videos

test-videos/**/*
```

Also I've added the following entry to .eslintrc.json

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*",
    "src/assets/test-videos/**/*"
  ],
  etc
}
```

But still no cigar. If the problem directory is not deleted ESLint just will not work! I suppose I could rename all the HLS files to use a non-standard extension but I'd rather not. Any ideas? Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks as if the settings in `.eslintignore` only affect errors reporting, whereas the settings in `tsconfig.json` affect parsing. Adding `"exclude": ["src/assets/test-videos"]` to the root `tsconfig.json` should help.

I've verified that it works the same when running eslint in terminal with `eslint src/**/*.*` - if the files are not excluded in `tsconfig.json`, ESLint runs out of memory

Comment: Thanks so much @lena

Answer (score 0):

@lena helped me all day fixing this! Thanks so much @lena

Just wanted to add the final solution.

In `.eslintrc.json` I added:

```
"ignorePatterns": [
  "src/assets/test-videos/**/*"
]
```

In `tsconfig.json` I added:

```
"exclude": [
  "src/assets/test-videos",
  "dist"
]
```

All of these changes were necessary for the fix. Removing any of them caused eslint to fail.

Note that the dist folder was generated after doing a build and also stopped eslint from working until I excluded it too.

One day lost but lessons learned!

BTW whilst this effected WebStorm it was not caused by WebStorm since `ng lint` was failing too. As soon as `ng lint` started working so did WebStorm.

Comment: One final note here - I think I also had to right click the problem test-videos folder within WebStorm and exclude it (in addition to the rest of the answer I've given here)