# eslint is super slow after updating angular from 12.0.2 to 12.2.12 because of import/no-deprecated

Tags: angular, eslint

After updating my Angular project to the latest stable version (12.2.12), suddenly the ESLint takes forever!

This is the timing table that is printed:

| Rule | Time (ms) | Relative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| import/no-deprecated | 223061.548 | 99.5% |
| jsdoc/check-alignment | 280.095 | 0.1% |
| @typescript-eslint/naming-convention | 134.618 | 0.1% |
| jsdoc/newline-after-description | 86.328 | 0.0% |
| prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions | 78.591 | 0.0% |
| id-match | 59.047 | 0.0% |
| object-shorthand | 43.973 | 0.0% |
| @typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing | 41.375 | 0.0% |
| @typescript-eslint/member-ordering | 32.891 | 0.0% |
| @typescript-eslint/semi | 31.701 | 0.0% |

`.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": false
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": [
          "off",
          {
            "accessibility": "explicit"
          }
        ],
        "arrow-parens": [
          "off",
          "always"
        ],
        "import/order": "off",
        "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
        "max-len": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
          "error",
          {
            "selector": "enum",
            "format": [
              "PascalCase",
              "UPPER_CASE"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Clearly, it's something with the latest update, did someone manage to solve this?

Comment: I had a similar problem using WebStorm IDE. Here's that post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69282492/eslint-cannot-start-language-service-process-problem-with-hls-ts-extension - some of it is likely to be irrelevant but I think you will find some relevant insights there that might help you fix this - particularly my own answer to my own question should be useful if you cant be bothered to read the full details

Comment: Note in relation to the above comment - whilst my issue initially appeared to be an IDE issue, it emerged it was actually not - the underlying problem was `ng lint` running slow / crashing - given that the IDE was using `ng lint` under the hood the IDE also suffered too - so whether you are using WebStorm or not my answer might help